# On the solution of a linear system of differential equations for the unknown series coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

In a mathematical physical problem, I came across the following linear system of differential equations (obtained upon using Fourier series expansion):
\begin{align}
  \frac{\mathrm{d} \rho_n}{\mathrm{d}  t} +
  \alpha \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d} \rho_i}{\mathrm{d} t} 
  &= - H_n \bigg( H_n \, \rho_n
  + \frac{\phi_n}{2} \bigg) +  1    \, , \\
  \frac{\mathrm{d}  \phi_n}{\mathrm{d}  t} 
  &= - H_n \, \rho_n - \phi_n \, ,
\end{align}
where 
$$
H_n = 2n-1 \, , 
\quad
\alpha \in \mathbb{R} \, ,
\quad
\text{and}
\,\,
n \ge 1\, .
$$

The system is subject to the initial conditions $\rho_n(0)=\phi_n(0)=0$.

> > The goal is to determine the general expression of the coefficients $\rho_n$ and $\phi_n$.
> >     When $\alpha=0$, the solution of the problem is easy and straightforward.

I have tried to solve the above linear system of differential equations for $\alpha \ne 0$ using the Laplace transform technique but without success. The calculation of the inverse Laplace transform doesn't seem to be possible (since the Laplace-transformed function has an infinite number of singularities and choosing an abscissa of convergence $\sigma>0$ for which the contour is located to the right of all singularities is not within reach.)

I was wondering whether someone here could be of help and try to tell how one can solve such a mathematical problem.
Your hints and ideas and very welcome.
Very much thanks!